# Python SSL post using requests

Tags: python, post, ssl, python-requests

The goal here is to be able to post username and password information to https://canvas.instructure.com/login so I can access and scrape information from a page once logged in.

I know the login information and the name of the login and password  (pseudonym_session[user_id], and pseudonym_sessionp[password]) but I'm not sure how to use the requests.Session() to pass the login page.

```
import requests
s = requests.Session()
payload = {'pseudonym_session[user_id]': 'bond', 'pseudonym_session[password]': 'james bond'}
r = s.post('https://canvas.instructure.com/login', data=payload)
r = s.get('https://canvas.instructure.com/(The page I want)')

print(r.content)
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: This has nothing to do with SSL. You need to know what kind of authentication mechanism they're using. Is it basic HTTP, digest HTTP, an application-level auth scheme that gives you a token in a cookie or form field that you have to send back with every request, or…? Every possibility is doable (and almost always easy), but until you know which one you're trying to do, it's impossible to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the code posted works fine. I had a spelling error on my end with the password. Now I'm just using beautiful soup to find what I need on the page after logging in.

Answer (score -1):

Put Chrome (or your browser of choice) into debug mode (Tools-> Developer Tools-> Network in Chrome) and do a manual login. Then follow closely what happens and replicate it in your code. I believe that is the only way, unless the website has a documented api.